# Transfer a file from Android to a PC (not in the same network)

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, android

If I were connected by wifi in my network, there isn't any problem because with AirDroid I can access the sdcard files using the browser.

However when I am out, how can I transfer a file from my phone to my PC? I can access my PC using SSH, but then from the PC I can't access the phone for get file using SCP.

I guess the question is: Is there any app that allow do such action? I think the only possible thing is install a SSH server in the phone, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean that you're using the phone and trying to put something on your PC, or are you on a third machine (like a work PC)? Where would you have been running the SSH command from?

Comment: The SSH client you're using on the phone may have an associated SCP or SFTP client. If it doesn't, there are others that do. [android.se] would be the right place to ask about those.

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite a solution to your problem but it may be a useful alternative: look into **Dropbox**; you can install it on linux as well as Android (and Windows, OSX, IOS, etc). It involves a sort of cloud share, so if you put a file in the box, you can now access it on any other device using that account:

https://www.dropbox.com/

I'm sure there are others services like this but I'm happy to recommend that one, it's simple, it works, it's free.  If you run a firewall on your PC you'll have to open a port for it, that's in the FAQ I think.

An advantage of that cloud server kind of thing is that you don't have to have all the devices on at the same time; you can put something in the box on one computer, turn it off, then turn on another computer and access it.

Comment: I don't like cloud services.

Comment: I honestly didn't either until I gave dropbox a try; they don't actually call it "cloud".  If it's a security issue, you could always splurge on a small VPS slice somewhere and apply the same principle.  Or just use your own encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can scp from phone to PC by entering the following command on the phone:

```
scp /path/to/file/on/phone user@pc:/path/to/file/on/pc
```

`scp` works both ways.

EDIT: You could also try an SFTP client like AndFTP (the free version).

Comment: Using scp would require you log in from the phone first. I think what yzT means is that if you are using your PC and you want to access the file system on the phone without physically accessing the phone to initiate the connection, then the phone must be running a server too.

Comment: I thought he was referring to starting out on his phone, trying to transfer to PC.

Comment: How you use scp on the phone? At least using terminal emulator it doesn't work.

Comment: @yzT You need an android ssh client that supports scp/sftp.  The one I use doesn't, but a quick google implies there are ones that do.

Comment: I use ConnectBot. Any suggestion?

Comment: AndFTP seems the best choice but 4.77€...

Comment: Does AndFTPFree support SFTP? If so, that works similarly to SCP.